# Action in collision detection (CGRectIntersectsRect)

Tags: objective-c, collision-detection

I have two images. You have to use a `acceleremoter` to move a man and avoid a big spike. Here is my .h coding:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *rect1;

IBOutlet UIImageView *rect2;
```

Here is my .m:

```
bool CGRectIntersectsRect ( CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2 );
```

I have connected everything in the nib file and I know nothing would happen because there was no error. I need these two things to collide and then generate an end screen. BUT *HOW* do I put an action in. THANKS!

.m

```
#import "GameScreen.h"


@implementation GameScreen
@synthesize ball, delta;


-(void)viewDidLoad {


    UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;
    accel.updateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;

    [super viewDidLoad];


}

-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    NSLog(@"x : %g", acceleration.x);
    NSLog(@"y : %g", acceleration.y);
    NSLog(@"z : %g", acceleration.z);

    delta.y = acceleration.y * 70;
    delta.x = acceleration.x * 70;

    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + delta.x, ball.center.y + delta.y);

    // Right
    if(ball.center.x < 0) {
        ball.center = CGPointMake(320, ball.center.y);
    }

    // Left

    if(ball.center.x > 320) {
        ball.center = CGPointMake(0, ball.center.y);

    }

    // Top

    if(ball.center.y < 0) {
        ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, 460);

    }

    // Bottom
    if(ball.center.y > 460){
        ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, 0);

    }


    }




bool CGRectIntersectsRect ( CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2 );



-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}






@end
```

Comment: Can you post the entire .m file

Comment: that is all I actually have about CGRects in the .m file but if u want it fine

Comment: What do you think bool CGRectIntersectsRect ( CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2 ); placed there?

Comment: I'll answer you, let me write

Comment: What do you think bool CGRectIntersectsRect ( CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2 ); placed there?     //im sorry i dont understand

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface GameScreen : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
 UIImageView *ball;
 CGPoint delta;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *rect1;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *rect2;
 IBOutlet UIImageView* hiddenView;
 IBOutlet UILabel* ready;
 IBOutlet UILabel* set;
 IBOutlet UILabel* go; 
 
 CAKeyframeAnimation *popAnimation;
}



@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;
@property CGPoint delta;
@end

Comment: im sorry for somereason i could not edit it

Answer (score 2):

Just before the end of

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
```

you have to put this code

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.bounds , man.bounds))
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"endScreenImage.png"];
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubView:imageview];
    [imageview release];
}
```

But I also think that you have to buy an Objective-C programming book and read it, instead of spamming StackOverflow with a lot of similar questions. I wrote that because I think it can be useful to you, not to make you angry.

Comment: well ok thanks but i have one question and im sorry, how can i define //Do something

Comment: another thing these images are just UIImageViews by the way, basically just screenshots from photoshop

Comment: //Do something is a comment, there you have to insert your own code to display an end screen.

Comment: You have also to replace ball and man with your corresponding UIImageView

Comment: i know, but how do i define the code since it is just a comment, like this //do something {code} (or something like that)

Comment: You have also to replace ball and man with your corresponding UIImageView  - of course i know that

Comment: just do [self.view addSubview:endScreen];

Comment: endScreen is your end screen UIImageView

Comment: ok then.... im sort of new so like im stuck..... although i know more code will have to go with [self.view addSubview:endScreen

Comment: where will i put  [self.view addSubview:endScreen];

Comment: I think that studying some theory could help you better understand code you could find there

Comment: and how do i make the app know what the subView is

Comment: If you don't know where to put it, how do you think you can make it working

Comment: ok that will help me correct, but right now that is not possible, so i am pleading you to help me

Comment: Put it instead of //Do something

Comment: ok, but then do i declare existence of that subview and how do i connect it and stuff like that.

Comment: and do i have to make it hidden

Comment: please help i am just so impatient and i need help so bad before i pick up a book

Comment: but should i put [endScreen setHidden:YES];

Comment: and do i need to say [reappear] or something like that

Comment: When you say addSubview it display it

Comment: it didnt work but i have a warning saying: UIView may not respond to addSubView i got it 2x

Comment: im getting this error now: 2011-05-01 13:06:10.345 Gravity Man[359:707] -[UIView addSubView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x151910

Comment: is there anyway i can give you like 100 more reputatipn

Comment: Just accept my answer and rate up all my comments. We can use chat later if you want to solve other problems

Comment: As indicated by the [answer to this user's later question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846698/trouble-with-cgrectintersectsrect-action/5846802#5846802), this should actually check the intersection of the two _frames_, not the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, just donne if its gonna work with ImageView's

init

```
[self schedule:@selector(update:)];
```

Make a void

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
...

CGRect absoluteBox = CGRectMake(ball.position.x, ball.position.y, [ball boundingBox].size.width, [ball boundingBox].size.height);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([ball boundingBox], [man boundingBox])) {
      // SOME CODE HERE         
    }
...

}
```